# Apple responds with "Missing Push Notification Entitlement" after update to xCode8 and iOS10

Tags: ios, cordova

In the details, the email i get from the itunes store says:

"the aps-environment entitlement is missing from the app's signature"

and

"make sure your App ID is enabled for push notification in the Provisioning Portal"

I can see in the portal that I have enabled Push Notifications for that app id, so i'm not sure how to proceed. Help?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on push notifications from Xcode 8.

Click on your project file, then click on capabilities from there you can turn on and off the push notifications.

[image]

Comment: Thanx! This is part of the solution. Now i need to figure out how to add this entitlement through Cordova config. Otherwise, with every build i'd need to enable the entitlement by hand in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Why apple send this mail to user don't know. Its just to tell you if you are using push notifications in your app than turn it on other wise forget it.

If you are not using push notifications in your app you have not to worry about it. Apple will surely approve your app if it didn't contain any other issue so be happy its just a warning

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1154), and is expected to be fixed in cordova-ios v4.3.0